# Is it idiomatic to use an infinitive in a question without finite verb or preposition?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, infinitif

In two journal articles, I came across a use of the infinitive in French that I'm not familiar with.

The first article is titled [Enseigner la vertu?](http://www.jstor.org/stable/41096618), and the second—which is a reply to the first—is titled [Pouvoir enseigner la vertu?](http://www.jstor.org/stable/41096619).

Both articles are about Plato's *Meno*, which concerns whether virtue is teachable. So I have a general idea that the first asks about teaching virtue and the reply asks about the ability to teach virtue.

However, I can't find any standard use of the infinitive in French that fits this context. Is it idiomatic? Or is there a standard use that I've missed in the grammars I've checked? (I would also be happy to hear what people think would be a good way to translate these titles, though I'm primarily concerned with understanding them rather than translation *per se*.)

Comment: It is not used very often. I guess the idea behind this is if a question is asked, you are not sure of your answer, so you will answer with the an interrogation mark, like "Depuis quand est-tu réveillé ?" , "Depuis... 1 heures environs ?". So here, the infinitive form may come from a question like "Comment régler les problèmes actuels de la société ?". Does it help ? :)

Comment: @Random It helps a little. If I understand, you mean that it's elliptical: by itself it doesn't make perfect sense, but the reader is supposed to supply something to fill out the thought. Is that right?

Comment: FYI, I would happily upvote either or both of these as an answer. They may not be definitive, but they both make excellent, helpful points. Thanks @PapaPoule and Random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may know, in french, proposition can be devoid of a finite verb (it is named "elliptique", and it is often associated to an independant proposition [see below]).
The first title corresponds to a proposition which is :

- [Infinitive](http://grammaire.cordial-enligne.fr/manuels/PROP_INFI.htm), it expresses an order, a defense, an exclamation, an interrogation or an affirmation;
- [Independant](http://grammaire.cordial-enligne.fr/manuels/PROP_IND.htm), because it isn't related to another proposition.

The second can be decomposed in two proposition :

- "Pouvoir" (main proposition) + "enseigner la vertu" ([subordinate](http://grammaire.cordial-enligne.fr/manuels/PROP_SUBO.htm) proposition).

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the use of the independent infinitive as a command, but I wasn't familiar with it as a question or an exclamation. The references were very helpful as well. (One thought: would it be better to say "devoid of a finite verb"? That is, there is an expressed verb—the infinitive, but not a finite one. But maybe the terminology is different in French.)

Comment: You are right, I correct this mistake.

Comment: This is not called a subordinate clause, it is simply… an infinitive clause.

Comment: The second proposition is subordinate to the first, am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

Titles of books/articles/films (but especially news headlines) don’t always follow grammar “rules,” and the two titles you mention **might** be examples of this, with “[Peut-on] and/or [Comment]” ellipted:

> “Peut-on/comment enseigner la vertu?”
>
> “Comment pouvoir enseigner la vertu?”

In scholarly articles like these, however, ellipted notions are often supplied in a suitable “sub-title”

> “[Pouvoir] Enseigner la vertu[?]: Est-ce vraiment possible?/[Comment
>   le faire ?]”

or (in another context)

> “Pousser les enfants[?]: Doit-on le faire?”),

so the lack of a “sub-title” in your two cases **could** signal that there’s another explanation.

They could instead possibly be examples of where someone hears a statement and is so amazed (usually in disagreement or disgust) by it that they repeat the essential part of the statement in a questioning tone (like when I told my horse-loving sister that she should try horse meat):

(Me): “Il faut manger du cheval, c’est vachement bon!”

(Sis): “Quoi? Manger du cheval?”

Regardless (especially with the "ellipted title" explanation), not having read the articles and based solely on their titles, I would hazard a guess that Dr. Barnes is asking
“How to teach virtue"
(which might imply that he **does** believe that it is possible),

whereas the second article’s author is asking
 “How is it possible to teach virtue”
(which might imply that he **doesn’t** think that it’s possible at all).

Comment: One thing in favor of what you say initially is that Barnes quotes an earlier scholar (Jowett), who asked "Peut-on enseigner la vertu?" So this suggests the elliptical question as you say.

Comment: *Comment pouvoir* is not idiomatic and sounds wrong.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez “Comment pouvoir + verb” definitely does have a redundant “feel” to it since “comment + verb” alone already kind of has the notion of “how **can** something be done” built in it, but would it sound/be equally wrong/unidiomatic if used to express and emphasize some predetermined negativity/desperation in certain contexts  (“[Je ne vois pas] *comment pouvoir* enseigner la vertu}, where “pouvoir” would mean more like “arriver à/réussir à”? Thanks!

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez As a French native, I agree that "Comment pouvoir" (whatever follows it) sounds at least clumsy. It's not even matter of high level or not: more likely it reveals a lack of culture. Why I point it is because the OP says it comes from a journal, and I'm afraid to observe that many journals, in France, from about fifteen years, saw their literary quality deteriorate rapidly. Before, they always could be regarded as a good reference , while now I wouldn't recommend to consider them as an example for French language learners.

Comment: To be fair to the authors of the two articles mentioned by the OP, they did not use “comment pouvoir” in their titles (nor, as far as I know, in the text of their articles). I, a non-native, clumsily suggested it in my answer. With that ([and this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comment+pouvoir&year_start=1650&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomment%20pouvoir%3B%2Cc0)) in mind, today’s sometimes maligned authors seem to misuse “comment pouvoir” far less in recent years than literary giants of past centuries misused it in their works. @cFreed

Comment: @PapaPoule Oops, you're right and my bad; after reading the whole page in its natural order, when seeing the Stephen's comment, by poor memory I erroneously related the offending "comment pouvoir" to the titles cited by the OP. And of course when I retrieve it's only your suggestion, I can't at all blame it the same, since you're non-native. On the other hand, unfortunately I must maintain what I said about the degradation I observe in our journals (not only the written press but also the radio: already five years ago, in a few time I recorded a list of 130 fouls at France Inter !).